# Oracle ADF postback error

Tags: oracle, oracle-adf

I am working on an application built using oracle ADF 10.1.2.17.87 and I see that the SQL loads each time the action class is invoked.

```
<action path="/search/SearchPage" ...>      
      <set-property property="modelReference" value="search_searchUIModel"/>
      <forward name="success" path="/search/searchPage.do"/>
    </action>

 <DCIterator
         id="SearchIterator"
         Binds="SearchModuleDataControl.SearchView"
         RSIName="null"
         RangeSize="10"               
         >
      </DCIterator>

<ViewObject
   Name="SearchView"
SelectList="empno,ename from employee"
/>
```

`RefreshCondition = #{adfFacesContext.postback == true}` does not work. It throws nullpointer exception. What else can I do to avoid full table load during initial load? are there any attributes that I can set to avoid this full table scan.

Answer (score 0):

use `AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance().isPostback()` in your managed bean constructor